# Unable to execute the test using Detox + Typescript + Expo in IOS

Tags: android, ios, typescript, expo, detox

My test is not being executed using Detox, expo and typescript.
Here is the snapshot of the error I am getting when running the test using command 'detox test --configuration ios.sim'
[failure error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB76o.png)

Here is my package.json looks like :-

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWWxx.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This tech isn't an area I'm strong in so I offer a suggestion for the question instead of a solution. You'll probably find you're going to get better quality responses with the text of your screenshots instead of just screenshots because responders will be able to copy and paste specific pieces and address them directly. Hope that helps!